# php writting to a file from a website not working

Tags: php, html

Im trying to write to file using php but it doesn't see to work.

```
$file = fopen("test.txt","w");
    fwrite($file,"Hello World!");
   fclose("$file");
```

I published the site using the school server. and the php file/text file are all in public_html folder. The problem is, running this into terminal writes the file. Running it as a website doesn't.

How do i fix this?

P.S. I've tried chmod 644, 777, 755

Comment: `chmod 777` should do the trick.

Comment: so where's the rest of the code that lets this run when accessed as a web page? You file can't just be these three lines.

Comment: no go, doesnt work :(

Answer (score 1):

Remove the quotes in `fclose` :

```
$file = fopen("test.txt","w");
fwrite($file,"Hello World!");
fclose($file);
```

Also, you have to grant all permission : see [that answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8328481/chmod-777-to-a-folder-and-all-contents).

Answer (score 0):

Hmm... is it a UNIX/Linux server?
You probably want to give the group `www-data` permissions to write the folder.

Assuming your web folder is `/var/www`, try doing this:

```
sudo chown `whoami`:www-data /var/www
sudo chmod 775 /var/www
```

And try again.
If you're working in your personal web folder (http://domain.ext/~yourusername), the commands should be:

```
chown `whoami`:www-data ~/public_html
chmod 775 ~/public_html
```

Does it work running the script now?