# Shell Script Invocation Error in Xcode 6

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode6

I used to compile universal static library with iOS-Universal-Framework, and works fine until I upgrade Xcdoe to 6.

I got the following error

```
** BUILD SUCCEEDED **
```

Create universal static library
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin/libtool -static /Users/taofang/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/xxxxx/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/xxx.framework/xxx /Users/taofang/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/xxxxx/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/xxx.framework/xxx -o /Users/taofang/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/xxxxx/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/xxx.framework/xxx.temp
error: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin/libtool: can't open file: /Users/taofang/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/xxxxx/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/xxx.framework/xxx (No such file or directory)

If i use Xcode 5 to do the job, it will be fine.

Beside, I selected Device as my compile target, but why the libtool tries to open a file under iphonesimulator folder?

Answer (score 3):

That means there are no header files in any of your build folders. It may be because you haven't configured your library project to export any header files.

Go to your Project Target >> Build Phases >> **+** sign >> Add a new build phase

You need to add a **Copy files** Phase that copies the headers you want to the include folder.

Comment: Sorry, it has header files inside.

Comment: I faced similar issues recently. Can you share your bash script? If not, just go over this merge - https://github.com/kwylez/StaticFramework-Sample-Project/issues/1 Are you good?

Comment: Double check *Search Paths* and *Public Headers Folder Path* too - `include/$(PROJECT_NAME)`.

Comment: how you fix that? My code in Xcode 5 works perfectly, only got problem with Xcode 6

Comment: Should not be an issue then. Can you check this? I know there is no direct solution - just something in the settings - https://github.com/kstenerud/iOS-Universal-Framework/issues/197

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `chmod a+x [PATH]`, I could resolve it with `chmod 777 [PATH]`.

Answer (score -1):

You can use the following command to recursively own all the files and folders in the path like...

```
chmod -R 777 ./
```

For more details:
[Chmod 777 to a folder and all contents](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8328481/chmod-777-to-a-folder-and-all-contents)