# XCode Framework/Library Objective C -- includes Header-Files I deleted from the project

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, frameworks, static-libraries

as the title says I created a library/framework quite a while ago. Now I am back at it to restructure the project -- to make several frameworks out of it. the idea is to have our whole project split up into several pieces(components).

So I copied the whole framework project and renamed it to something different. then I went on and deleted all the stuff from the project I dont want in this framework --at this very example-- all the business objects and the data access layer classes were both in this project-- but I want the data access layer classes to be included in their own framework.

when i go on and build this framework -- lets call it the business-object-framework (boFramework) -- it builds alright. but as soon as I reference it from the data-access-layer-framework (daFramework) I get a conflict saying it has this reference already or duplicates are not allowed (or such..)
and true -- when I look into the framework, I can see lots of the da-classes I deleted from the boFramework-project.
I poke around with this for quite a while now but i have no idea where xcode gets the information of these deleted files. there are not in the project, not in svn or somewhere else. if I search for them in the project or the filesystem i dont get a result.
I "cleaned" it dozen of times-- with no effect. as soon as I build the framework again it will include these header files. I really dont know where Xcode holds on to these references -- how can i get rid of these headers I dont want in this project??

did anyone experience the same issue?? any suggestions appreciated- thanks!
I give up!!

Comment: Are you building it in the same project, or in separate projects?  If the source files are still in the project, double-check that they aren't being copied to both frameworks.  If they are not, look in the build steps for the daFramework and make sure there aren't unexpected Copy Files steps in there.  One good way to find out what's going on is to hold down the option key and Clean the project and then rebuild and check the build log searching for the name of a file that shouldn't be there.

Comment: thank you for your suggestions-- i did this-- now i get a error saying "No such file or directory" -- as xcode is trying to copy something from the ressources.bundle
any idea how to fix this??

Comment: Unfortunately, you're probably just going to have to track down which pieces are included in the wrong (or no frameworks and manually check them.

Answer (score 0):

thanks gaige...
well... I was able to solve this-- after gaige's suggestions i received a different error....
by looking through other posts -- i found this:
[shell script invocation error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26051761/shell-script-invocation-error-in-xcode-6)

i had this build phasis already ... but it was empty for some reason. so i added all the header files and it would build alright. but then i received lots of warnings --- and the reason for that was because I made my header-files public. header files should be situated underneath the project-dropdown. not the public one.
in case someone hits the same problem .... hope this helps. send me some fruits! (gaige too)