# dir1 and dir2 chmod 700, dir3 chmod 777 but I am getting Permission denied

Tags: linux, permissions, file-permissions, chmod

I am learning Linux and permissions.

I have following folders `dir1/dir2/dir3` and the file `myfile.txt` within `dir3`.
I am trying to give permission `chmod 700` to `dir1` and `dir2` to both folders and files but to all files and folders within `dir3` I want to give permission `chmod 777`.

**According to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8328481/chmod-777-to-a-folder-and-all-contents) post I did following:**

To change permission for `dir1` and all the directories within `dir1` to  `chmod 700`

`find /home/user/dir1 -type d -exec chmod 700 {} \;`

To change all the files within `dir1` to  `chmod 700` including the sub-folders

`find /home/user/dir1 -type f -exec chmod 700 {} \;`

**After that I did following:**

To change permission to `dir3` and all the directories within `dir3` to `chmod 777`

`find /home/user/dir1/dir2/dir3 -type d -exec chmod 777 {} \;`

To change permission to all the files within `dir3` to `chmod 700`

`find /home/user/dir1/dir2/dir3  -type f -exec chmod 777 {} \;`

When I check permission with `ls -al` everything looks fine but when I change the user and try to get access to `dir3` and `myfile.txt` I am always getting message **"Permission denied"**  .

What am doing wrong? 
Is there some better way to do that I want?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

700 means that only the owner of dir1 and dir2 have rwx access to dir1 and dir2. If some other user will try to access the inside the dir1 or dir2 he will not be allowed irrespective of 777 inside dir3.So please check that your user is the owner.
One solution is to give 770 to dir1 and dir2 this will allow the group( you have to specify ) to have rwx permission.Then you can add your user in the group so that only this user has rwx access not the other users.