# File path in NextJS api route not resolving

Tags: next.js, vercel

I'm trying to resolve a file path in [NextJS](https://nextjs.org/).

I understand that [API routes](https://nextjs.org/docs/api-routes/introduction) are working a little bit differently when deployed to Vercel. In order to create a correct path to the file I assumed I had to do this:

```js
const svg = fs.readFileSync(
  path.join(process.cwd(), "img", "file.svg"),
  "utf-8",
);

// ENOENT: no such file or directory
```

But I cannot make it work. **The file cannot be found under that path.**

How can I find the correct path for a file in NextJS api routes?

I've followed the [documentation](https://vercel.com/guides/loading-static-file-nextjs-api-route) of this.

- Next version is: 11.1.3
- When logging the path, it is giving `/var/task/packages/project-root/img/file.svg`

Comment: what error message are you getting back?

Comment: @fredrivett file not found under said path

Comment: try using `__dirname` to reach your desired path instead of `process.cwd()`

Comment: Thanks, but does not work.

Comment: @supersize Am I correct in assuming that your `pages` folder is on the same level as your `svg` folder?

Comment: @JonathanWieben I guess you are referring to the `img` folder, but yes you are correct. Both in root.

Comment: @supersize Yes, I did. However, the logged path in your message reads `/svg/file.svg` while in your code it says `img`. Are you positive you are referencing the correct path?
I tried doing the same thing you are doing in one of my next apps and it did work.

Comment: @JonathanWieben yeah that is not the issue, it was a typo while formulating the question. I amended it to be correct. I double-checked this multiple times.

Comment: @supersize I simulated this scenario and this works both locally and on production (Vercel). Can you paste the error from Vercel function logs (https://vercel.com/docs/concepts/deployments/logs) here?

Comment: @SonNguyen sure, the error is `ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/var/task/packages/frontend/img/file.svg'`

Comment: @supersize no luck, I cant reproduce your error. Desperate question, is there any chance your project is a monorepo, because I see the packages folder.

Comment: I don't think next.js API routes supports file reading without some workarounds. These links might help: https://github.com/vercel/next.js/discussions/32236 and https://medium.com/@boris.poehland.business/next-js-api-routes-how-to-read-files-from-directory-compatible-with-vercel-5fb5837694b9

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For anyone coming across this, I actually opened a ticket at Vercel to ask them about this.

It turns out it was a caching issue that is caused by using `Yarn 3`

The support redirected me to this [page](https://vercel.com/guides/does-vercel-support-yarn-2) explaining that they would have issues with anything above Yarn 1.

According to them there is nothing really they can do about right now but suggest us to use a different package manager.

Answer (score 0):

Try using

```
path.resolve("img", "file.svg")
```

Maybe it should help.

Comment: Unfortunately the issue persists

Answer (score 0):

Pretty sure you'll find the file if you serve it as a static file - [Next.js documentation here](https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/static-file-serving)

I'm thinking it's not bundled in the deployment, but whatever you have in `/public` will definitely be deployed.

Good luck

Comment: I wish it would be true, but it does not work with `public` either.

Comment: Your code does work for me locally. The problem is when deployed to Vercel?

Comment: This works for me on Vercel: fs.readdirSync('./public/img')

Comment: Correct, only failing when deployed to Vercel. Can you confirm your code example `fs.readdirSync('./public/img')`works for an api route?

Comment: You’re right, it doesn’t work from api. Doesn’t find the file. The same function works from getStaticProps (the website is built around it) but not /api/ ‍♂️ probably the dynamic vs static environments...
If you put it in /public/ can't you just "import" the file and use it within the code? Next.js should take care of the magic wiring...
Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

I manage to create a small sandbox that will clarify your issue. Open it using [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/nextjs-bhsdra?file=pages%2Findex.js)

**Project Structure**

```
.
├── pages
|   ├── api
|   |   ├── hello.js
|   ├── _app.js 
|   ├── index.js
├── public
|   ├── 1.txt --> this is a demonstration file
```

I reproduce your code in the `hello` api for testing purposes

```
const { readFileSync } = require('fs');
const { join } = require('path');

export default (req, res) => {
  const path = join(process.cwd(), '/public/1.txt');
  const value = readFileSync(path, { encoding: 'utf-8' });
  res.status(200).json({ value });
};
```

This API entry is called from the `index.js` file

```
import Head from 'next/head';
import { useEffect, useState } from 'react';

export default function Home() {
  const [value, setValue ] = useState('');

  useEffect(() => {
    fetch('/api/hello')
    .then((res) => res.json())
    .then(data => setValue(data.value));
   });
   
  return (
    <div>
      <Head>
        <title>Create Next App</title>
      </Head>

      <main>
        <h1>{value}</h1>
      </main>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Yes, this is a very simplified version (for testing purposes only.. I assume we won't use `readFileSync` in production) - but - it reproduces your code.

Unfortunately, it works perfectly fine in dev mode and in production mode (`npm run build` + `npm start`), which means:

- You either misconfigured your `img` folder
- Perhaps you are lacking read permissions for the path you are using. For instance if you deploy your work to a remote machine, most directories will have limited access and therefore prevent you from reading the file (for testing this theory please [read this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8328481/chmod-777-to-a-folder-and-all-contents) post and execute it on your deployed machine)

Comment: it works fine for me locally as well. It stops working for Vercel deployments. I will recreate your code once more exactly like that.

Comment: Yeah it does not work. I am getting the same error in the public folder with the exact same setup as yours.

Comment: Also this example does not deploy to Vercel, which is the problem I think.

Comment: that's why I added the `permissions` section to my answer. please verify that you have proper access rights to the path that you are trying to read files from (and please use the link I 've added to properly execute it)

Comment: first of all I appreciate your input on this. I don't think this will be the issue as the folders are created by running the next command and they didn't get changed. But nevertheless I created a new app and by comparing it I can see that both folders are the same chmod rights: `drwxr-xr-x`, so unfortunately this isn't it either.

Comment: ok.. can you please share which value your `outputDirectory` field has inside `vercel.json` config file?

Comment: btw.. have you downloaded the sandbox l that I created locally to your computer ant try it? just ensure that you know that this project can be downloaded as zip and properly edited locally

Comment: should the `vercel.json` be in the root of Next? Because we don't have one then.

Comment: according to the docs https://vercel.com/docs/concepts/deployments/configure-a-build#output-directory - if you omit configuration the `public` folder is set to default. hence, using the `pulic` folder should work. if you are still suing your `img` folder instead than yes - you should add `vercel.json` file and configure it

Answer (score 0):

I'm using Yarn 1.22, but still have this issue. The reason is because files are not generated during build and run times, so they are never found. The way to get around this is to create a separate `.js` file that to wrap around the said static files (html, txt, etc). Export this JS object which contains the files, and Vercel will generate them. I'm using this to generate email templates.

```
//account_verify.js
import path from 'path';
import { promises as fs } from 'fs';
import { prefixPath } from './constants';

// TODO: force this to conform to a typescript type
export default {
    subject: 'Confirm Your Account',
    data: {
      email_verification_link: '{{email_verification_link}}',
      first_name: '{{first_name}}'
    },
    templates: {
      txt: fs.readFile(path.join(process.cwd(), prefixPath, 'account_verify.txt'), 'utf8'),
      html: fs.readFile(path.join(process.cwd(), prefixPath, 'account_verify.html'), 'utf8'),
    }
  };
```