# Vercel Error: ENOENT no such file or directory

Tags: javascript, node.js, vercel

I'm building a static blog using Nextjs 13 and deploying it on Vercel. I builded and started the project locally and everything was working, but on Vercel I got this error:

> ERROR Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'posts/second.md'    at Object.openSync (node:fs:600:3)    at Object.readFileSync (node:fs:468:35)    at getPostBySlug (/var/task/.next/server/chunks/207.js:146:63)    at Post (/var/task/.next/server/app/posts/[slug]/page.js:603:52)    at T (/var/task/.next/server/chunks/760.js:11441:25)    at Ma (/var/task/.next/server/chunks/760.js:11604:33)    at Array.toJSON (/var/task/.next/server/chunks/760.js:11397:32)    at stringify ()    at V (/var/task/.next/server/chunks/760.js:11696:53)    at ping (/var/task/.next/server/chunks/760.js:11496:43) {  errno: -2,  syscall: 'open',  code: 'ENOENT',  path: 'posts/second.md'}

**The error happens when I go to the "/posts/second" route for example, not in the main page**

This is the code interested:

```
const getPostBySlug = (slug: string) => {
const folder = "posts/";
const file = `${folder}${slug}.md`;
const content = fs.readFileSync(file, "utf8");
return matter(content)
};
```

The *posts* folder is located in the root folder.

I tried to modify the next config by adding the *output* option and setting it to *'standalone'*:

```
const nextConfig = {
   // config
   output: 'standalone',
}
```

I also tried to modify the path to locate the folder but nothing seems to work.

If more information is needed. project is published on [GitHub](https://github.com/Samuele1818/personal-blog)

Comment: I tested this on my end, and it works perfectly fine. I would suggest restarting the server since these types of "random" errors often occur, and the fix is just to restart the server.

Comment: I deleted and recreated the project on Vercel but it's not working, I forgot to specify that the error happens when I go to the "/posts/second" route for example, not in the main page.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I solved my problem by looking at [a tutorial provided by Vercel](https://vercel.com/guides/loading-static-file-nextjs-api-route), so thanks to this line of code `path.join(process.cwd(), 'posts');` the folder path is resolved.

Comment: What is `process.cwd()` with respect to path of `posts`?  I'm having a similar issue 

I currently have files inside the following folder, and it did not work:

`path.join(process.cwd(),\`/pages/api/email/email-templates/${templateNameTxt}\`),`

Comment: I think you have to move the `email-templates` folder into the root folder (so the path of the dir will be `/email-templates`), and then change the code to `path.join(process.cwd(), 'email-templates/)`. Now you have access to the folder and you can read the files that it contains using the `fs`.

Comment: I've been suffering from this bug for 3+ days, just a note for those who are going through this issue: Vercel only supports Yarn 1, so anything 2+ is going to have this issue. I have pretty much read every blog and documentation for the past 3 days and have not solved this problem. https://vercel.com/guides/does-vercel-support-yarn-2

discovered this issue via this StackOverflow thread: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74529208/file-path-in-nextjs-api-route-not-resolving

Comment: Also, you cannot have variable in your template names, ie. `/pages/api/email/email-templates/${templateNameTxt}` will not be accepted. Only the exact template file name will be recognized. this is because the template file variable is not found at build time and Vercel throws an error.

Answer (score 0):

*(Not sure if this is the exact same problem!)*

I solved it by **removing the "api" folder** from the pages directory.

- Pre-build, and check if al the pages get build statically
  indicated by: '○' or '●'
  and non dynamic: 'λ'
- In my case the app did not deploy on Vercel.
- *(Don't know why the error references a completely different file)*

*feel free to correct me if I'm wrong
just hoping people don't go ghost hunting (like me) when it might be an easy fix =)*

Answer (score 0):

I wasn't able to solve this with `process.cwd()`, instead i used `path.resolve`.

Example:

```js
await fs.readFile(path.resolve("src/path/to/file/file.js"), "utf8",)
```